# Adapt text length in postgres

Tags: postgresql

My starting text is "BP" (2 characters) and I would like to adjust my text to 5 characters, like "000BP" or "   BP" (3 spaces before BP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `LPAD`:

```
SELECT LPAD('BP', 5, '0')

SELECT LPAD('BP', 5, ' ')
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2a4d4124306940441b04a1a0785d1eb6)**

Comment: Thanks for this answer!